# Error:Option Clash for package color

Tags: beamer, color

I am new to LaTeX.I was trying to make my first presentation using beamer.I downloaded the required packages ,but I was getting this error

```
!Latex Error:Option clash for package color.
```

Here is the code, which I copied from [here](http://kenjokenjo.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/how-to-install-latex-and-beamereasy/)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I read about this error [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59848/how-to-circumvent-option-clash-for-package-error). I also read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/conflict-between-color-graphicx-and-libertine) post,but I don't know which packages are using the color package and which package (beamerthemesplit,amsfonts,amssynb) is causing this conflict.

What should I do?

Comment: remove `[pdftex]` the system will detect that it is on pdftex and supply it automatically, and the option clash will go away

Comment: All the packages you're requiring are already loaded by `beamer`, except `color`, but the class loads `xcolor`. Say `\usepackage` in documents, rather than `\RequirePackage`. All the common packages are able to automatically supply the correct option corresponding to the TeX engine used, so passing `pdftex` is *very rarely* needed (and only for some rather esoteric package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to David's suggestion, I think this is not a standard `beamer` code. Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{split}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

From [beameruserguide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section "2.6 Compatibility with Other Packages and Classes" (page 16).

> `\usepackage{color}`
>
> PRESENTATION: The `color` package is automatically
>   loaded by `beamer.cls`. This makes it impossible to pass options to
>   `color` in the preamble of your document in the normal manner. To pass a
>   `list of options` to `color`, you can use the following class option:
>
> `\documentclass[color=⟨list of options⟩]{beamer}`
>
> Causes the `list of options` to be passed on to the `color` package. If the `list of
>   options` contains more than one option you must enclose it in curly
>   brackets.
>
> ARTICLE: The `color` package is not loaded automatically if
>   `beamerarticle` is loaded with the `noxcolor` option.

So, you should use `\documentclass[color=pdftex]{beamer}`, although as David already commented, `pdftex` option is not needed.