# How can I use a usepackage only for one section?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, packages, texinputs

I need 2 different usepackages: one for a floatchart ( http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) and one for my whole document.

.

**For the Floatchart:**

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
```

**For my document:**

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

If I insert both, texmaker says: *option clash for package graphicx and for package inputenc.*

What can I do? Can I specify the usepackage for the floatchart only for the floatchart?

Comment: The flowchart cannot be made with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead?

Comment: In this case (assuming that you can not get rid of the clash by adapting the options), you should write your flowchart in an own document of the `standalone` class. You may load the `standalone`-package in your main document in order to include the spare files easily. Or you just include the pre-compiled pdfs.

Comment: Remove the `pdftex` option for `graphicx`, and remove `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Be aware, that the option `pdftex` should not be given.

Comment: Thank you so far...I can't use the standalone class, because I use the \input code for my floatchart: \input{floatchart.tex} - and because of that I can not type \begin{document} in my floatchart.tex.

Comment: If I delete pdftex and \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} like Torbjørn T. recommended: Texmaker tells me: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels = 255] ....   =(

Comment: Anyway, that `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}` is present is not a clash, it can be safely applied to the two parts of your document.

Comment: You can convert `floatchart` from `latin1` coding to `utf8`. There are external tools to do this ([iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)), [online tools](http://i-tools.org/charset) but some text editors can also make this conversion (texworks does it).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know where this `[pdftex]` habit originates but you don't need to use it. You can read a few answers on this site too about it but in a nut shell, most modern packages know what the current driver is and they can decide. Providing a fixed option is only looking for trouble.

In your example, TikZ already loads `graphicx` so you don't need to do anything. Just load TikZ and you are good to go. If for some reason you don't want to include the package then include it as a picture.

So, using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
```

and it should work for both sections. Instead of font and input encoding, I would go with LuaTeX though.

Some reading;

[Conflict between color, graphicx and libertine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/conflict-between-color-graphicx-and-libertine)

[Option clash when using graphicx and tikz packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82153/option-clash-when-using-graphicx-and-tikz-packages)

[Is it possible to load a TikZ library locally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/is-it-possible-to-load-a-tikz-library-locally)

Answer (score 6):

Both option/package combinations can be easily merged:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Of course different drivers cannot be used for parts of the document. If you are using `pdflatex`, then option `pdftex` can be omitted, because the standard `graphics.cfg` of MiKTeX or TeX Live is able to detect pdfTeX in PDF mode and sets the option appropriately.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The input encoding for the document:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

If the flow chart is using `latin1`, then the input encoding can be changed in the mid of the document via `\inputencoding`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
\begin{document}
% UTF-8 stuff
% ...
\inputencoding{latin1}
% Flowchart with text in latin1
% ...
\inputencoding{utf8}
% Back to UTF-8
```

Or `latin1` can be set locally:

```
\begingroup
  \inputencoding{latin1}
  % Flowchart with text in latin1
  % ...
\endgroup
% back to previous input encoding
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage[something]{inputenc}
```

tells LaTeX which ***input encoding*** to expect. This is the encoding that your document is saved in.

You cannot save your document in two different encodings. (You could make two copies - one per encoding - but a single file has a single encoding.)

So you cannot use both

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

for the same document as you are effectively telling LaTeX, 'Hey, I'm a file encoded in both latin1 and utf8!' and that obviously cannot be true. Encodings apply to files and not parts of files.

If you ***really*** need the flow chart in a different encoding (but why?), then you would need to compile it as a distinct document and include it as a graphic, for example, or as a PDF if it is a stand-alone page.

Note that your package calls are dealing with ***two distinct kinds of encoding***: input encodings (`inputenc`) and output/font encodings (`fontenc`).

```
\usepackage[something]{fontenc}
```

specifies the output font encodings to be used. Unlike input encodings, you ***can*** switch between these encodings within a document. (In fact, LaTeX will essentially do this whatever you do when it sets up the fonts for mathematics.)

Answer (score 1):

```
\iftrue
%\iffalse
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
  \usepackage{tikz} 
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\else
  \usepackage{graphicx} 
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
```

In this case the first three are used. If you comment `\iftrue` and uncomment `\iffalse` it will be the other way round.

Comment: This will not permit to have a package only for one section or I haven't understand your point `:/`